# Number of possible values for a sum of $n$ variables

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $x_k\in \{2^k,-2^k\}$ where $k\in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

> I am trying to check if the possible values for $y:=x_0+x_1+\ldots +x_{n-1}$ are unique?

I was trying to prove that they are indeed unique by induction. If $y=x_0$, they are unique. By induction hypothesis, let the possible values for $y=x_0+x_1+\ldots +x_k$ be unique but am not sure how to apply that for the sum of $k+1$ terms. Any ideas for proving or disproving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction is one technique that is common to try out. I don't know that that pans out very well here. Consider what would happen to the (hypothetical) first $n$ that allows non-uniqueness. You would have a $y$ that is written in two different ways where the $x_{n-1}$ are necessarily distinct. What can the induction hypothesis say about the remaining $x_i$? Not much, as they don't sum to the same value: one set sums to $y-2^{n-1}$ and the other set sums to $y+2^{n-1}$. I'm not saying it can't be done, but it doesn't feel natural.

Another approach, that is often suited to proofs of uniqueness of things, is to study the difference between two potentially distinct things. (Not necessarily the *subtraction* between the things, although that works often enough.)

Take a number $y$ that can be written in two such ways, and subtract those two ways, term-by-term. Now you have $0$ written on the form
$$
0 = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}
$$
where $a_k \in \{-2\cdot2^k, 0, 2\cdot 2^k\} = \{0, \pm 2^{k+1}\}$. For contradiction, let $i$ be the smallest index such that $a_i\neq 0$. Now consider whether the right-hand side of the equality above is divisible by $2^{i+2}$.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I did not understand why we are checking divisibility by $2^{i+2}$? I see that $a_i\in\{\pm 2^{i+1}\}$,

Comment: @manifolded We check for divisibility by $2^{i+2}$ because that works. Try it, see what happens. Is $a_i$ divisible by $2^{i+2}$? What about the lower-index terms? What about the higher-index terms? What about the entire sum?

Comment: Sorry, I still did not understand what the check gives us. If $i$ is the only index such that $a_i\neq 0$, then the sum $a_0+a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n-1}$ is $2^{i+1}$ and is hence not divisible by $2^{i+2}$. I'm not sure what that means? Thanks.

Comment: @manifolded ($i$ is the _first_ such index, not the _only_ such index.) Is the left-hand side of that equality divisible by $2^{i+2}$? For there to be an equality, ought the right-hand side be divisible by $2^{i+2}$?

Comment: Yes, LHS is divisible. Lower index terms are divisible, $a_i$ is not divisible and the higher index terms are divisible and hence a contradiction?

Comment: @manifolded Exactly: Only one term on the RHS is non-divisible, so the sum is non-divisible. But that contradicts the equality as $0$ is clearly divisible.

Comment: Perfect, good logic :)